# What are these feathered arrows in Schmitt’s triads?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

[image: downward arrows]
What do these feathered arrows mean?

Answer (score 1):

They're simply drawing attention to the fingering.  These arpeggios [in every other key](https://archive.org/details/preparatoryexerc00schm/page/24) use a 1-2-4-5 fingering for right hand in this inversion.  The arrows just are highlighting the fact that one should note the 3rd finger use in these few keys.

Comment: Odd that there's no similar marking in the lower finger patterns (5421 vs 5321)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: The lower finger patterns don't vary dependent on key (for whatever reason).